# new word or mispleing of existing word in old dictionary?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I know my question is kind of general and wide but I wrote it to narrow it down by your idea!

Lets say we have an incomplete dictionary of very old language and we want to complete it! There are a lot of documents contain sentences.

At the first we fill the dictionary by the closest language to this old language. Most of the words match 100% with dictionary but some words match with some penalty in mismatch letter!

Is there any machine learning or statistical method to assign some sort of posterior error probability by using the frequency of each letters in each document to say:

1) the letter, which mismatched is incorrect and by correct it you don't need to add this word to your dictionary!

OR

2) the letter, which mismatch is confident enough and you should count this word as a new word in your dictionary!

Sorry again for asking general question!

Comment: This may be more appropriate for http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welll! I don't know maybe someone by the tag, which I assign can come up with an idea!

Comment: It seems like you are looking for a statistical model of misspelling first. You'll need to consult a linguist for that...